# SQL inject MariaDB with SQLMAP

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap, mariadb

I'm fairly new to sqlmap but I have tried a lot of attacks and have been successful except for this one attack that I have tried. SQLMAP won't detect this nor try to inject an error like this.

So how ik that the site is vulnerable well.
I used http-headers and edited a value which was:

`Client-IP: 1'"`

Now I tried all attacks on the site it was amazingly protected and not vulnerable to any attacks but then I noticed changing the `client-IP` to `1'"` gave an error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"'' at line 1`

However I tried almost all commands and I'm not really sure why sqlmap won't detect even a little bit of anything.

Can anyone help me out with like a command or something or explain why the site is not injectable.

Answer (score 1):

SQLMap is a great tool if used in correct manner. we need to specify the correct injection point in the complete query of SQLMap
like for example in case of get method used in html form

```
sqlmap.py -u "www.example.com/file.php?id=1" --dbs //here injection is already specified.
```

but if its a post method we need to change our query

```
sqlmap.py -u "www.example.com/file.php" --method="POST" --data"email=ex@ex.com&pass=pass" -p pass --dbs
```

here pass is the injectable parameter and it will run all its test on this parameter

sometimes header injection exists like for example when the php code takes the ip of the user and doesn't sanitise it

```
sqlmap -u "http://www.example.com/file.php?id=1" --headers=”X-Forwarded-For: *” --dbs
```

now the sqlmap will run its test on the headers also i.e X-forwarded-for

SQLMap doesnt perform injections on the headers directly unless its specified.
I think this might answer your query

Comment: have tried this before, like i said i have completed almost every possible test on it... it is vulnerable just need some help here

Comment: which header are you exactly referring to.
You usually need to provide sqlmap with the specific request that you want to test for SQL injections.sqlmap can't reliably analyze the web application and recognize the injectable parameters by itself.